# Read and write all files from a directory in nodejs

Tags: node.js, node-modules, fs

Current Code:

```
 var fs = require('fs')

fs.readdir('C:\Users\Eva\Desktop\Main\Input', (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  files.forEach(file => {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err,result) {
      if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
      }
      result = //logic;

      fs.writeFile('C:\Users\Eva\Desktop\Main\Output',result,'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
      });
  });
});



});
```

My input would be one folder with all the files and output would be another folder with output files.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Start by getting all the files from a certain directory, then iterate them and for each one call your functions (above)

Comment: What does this have to do with Node-RED?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code you can use to iterate a folder and get all files within the folder.

```
var fs = require('fs')

fs.readdir('/folder/with/files', (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  files.forEach(file => {
    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err,result) {
      if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
      }
      result = //logic;

      fs.writeFile('/new/file/path',result,'utf8', function (err) {
        if (err) {
          return console.log(err);
        }
      });
  });
});
```

Make sure your logic is synchronous and runs sequentially. Otherwise use promises. For basis file manipulation this should suffice

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.I am getting cannot read forEach Property undefined. The above code the closing brackets. I also tried to use ReadFileSync and writeFileSync.

Comment: Thank you for updating the code. Please bear with me until I am able to run it successfully.I have folder named Main folder on the desktop that has two folders named "Input" and "Output". The script named Verification.js is outside of the folders named "Input" and "Output" folder and inside the "Main" folder.
I have updated the program in the question.

Comment: I get the error: 
C:\Users\Eva\Desktop\Main>node Verification.js
{ [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\Eva\Desktop\MainUsersEvaDesktopMainInput']
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'scandir',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\Eva\\Desktop\\Main\\UsersEvaDesktopMainInput' }

Comment: I ran npm install again just to make sure the server is up. Am I entering the path incorrectly? Should the path be added like 'C:\Users\Eva\Desktop\Main\Input' OR '\C:\Users\Eva\Desktop\Main\Input\'?

Comment: I also ran  npm rebuild node-sass.